# Does my column numbers and structure for bootstrap widths even make sense?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Just started learning Bootstrap and for example have designed this form like this, I want to know if those column numbers even make sense according to each other?

```
<form class="form-horizontal">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Website Active
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <label>Display this message when the website is not active</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: A row will "reset" your cols so it's maybe better to group your `col-sm-6` into one single row and also put your `form` into it.

Comment: thanks, @VincentG , what does it mean that row will "reset" columns? I am new to this, can you please explain what is the effect of resetting?

Comment: This means a row tag must have 12 columns by default. If you have only 6 column inside your "row" tag, this is incorrect

Comment: "reset" may not be the perfect term. A row is divided in (mostly) 12 columns so you have to deal a row with 12 columns. In your case, you use 6 columns in each row which could work but you will not have the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See here](http://www.bootply.com/ugnoIXlrWd) the difference of what I explained in comments :

In your case, a more proper structure could be :

```
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox"> Website Active
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Display this message when the website is not active</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
             </div>
```

And you have to add a `.container` or `.container-fluid` class around your `.row`

You can have `.row` as much as you wants in a single `.container` class.

[See your code on a bootply fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/un3V39RtGG)